# Ajax populated fields on Symfony2 (category populates sub category)

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony

I want to populate a sub category when I choose a category from a select box.
I followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) (and many many other things on the Internet for days), but I feel like it is not meant to be used with Ajax, thus not using dynamic forms like I want it to be.

Any idea how I can do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a controller, which will process your ajax requests (i.e. response with categories json). Then you should write a JS code onto your form page, which will request this controller action, process response and update your selectbox

I.e you have a controller with route name `categories_ajax_path` which reponse a JSON like

```
[
  {'label':'some category 1','id':1,'group':'group 1'},
  {'label':'some category 2','id':2,'group':'group 2'},
  {'label':'some category 3','id':3,'group':'group 1'}
]
```

Then add script to the page like this

```
<script>
        $.getJSON('{{ path('categories_ajax_path') }}', function (data) {

            var opt_groups = {};

            $.each(data, function (i, value) {
                if (!(value.season in opt_groups))
                    opt_groups[value.group] = [];

                var opt = $('<option/>');
                opt.val(value.id);
                opt.text(value.title);

                opt_groups[value.group].push(opt);
            });

            for (var group in opt_groups) {
                if (!opt_groups.hasOwnProperty(group)) continue;

                var $opt_group = $("<optgroup/>", {'label': group});

                opt_groups[season].forEach (function ($item){
                    $opt_group.append($item);
                });

                $('#category_list').append($opt_group);
            }

        })
</script>
```

The problem is that ajax populated forms might not pass symfony builtin validations (because this is not the choices symfony expect), so you need additional tweaks